# How to create a Decision Tree from a Collection of decisions?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I'm asked to make a constructor for a Decision Tree class, but I have no idea how to approach it.

**The question asks:**

Write a constructor for the Decision Tree class, which takes in a sorted array of
instances, and constructs recursively a tree that splits the data until all leaves are pure. .

Here is the Decision Tree class I have to program:

```
package DecisionTree;

public class DecisionTree {

public DecisionTree(Instance[] instances) {

// code goes here
}

public void prune() {
// code goes here
}

public boolean classify(double input) {
// code goes here
}

public void print() {
// code goes here
 }
}
```

I am also provided with these methods:

First:

```
package DecisionTree;

public class DTNode {

    Instance[] a;
    double testValue;
    DTNode left, right;

    // code goes here
}
```

Second:

```
package DecisionTree;

public class Instance {

    double attribute;
    boolean label;

    public Instance(double a, boolean c) {
    attribute = a;
    label  = c;
    }

    public double getAttribute() {
    return attribute;
    }

    public void setAttribute(double a) {
    attribute = a;
    }

    public boolean getLabel() {
    return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(boolean c) {
    label = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, write some code!

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with constructors - it's merely about turning a simply flat collection into an appropriate tree structure.

Comment: What is this for?  A class?  Is it supposed to be used for machine learning?  If so, you should use Weka--if it's for class or not for machine learning, then disregard this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I found useful when implementing my version of decision tree. Of course you would need to modify few things.

http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~frans/OldLectures/COMP101/AdditionalStuff/javaDecTree.html